# python, matrix column extraction and sum

Tags: python, arrays, data-analysis

Say I have a matrix `A = [a_1,a_2,...,a_n]`. Each column `a_i` belongs to a class. All classes are from 1 to K. All n column's labels are stored in one n-dim vector b.

Now for each class i, I need to sum all vectors in class i together and put the result vector as the i-th column of a new matrix. So the new matrix has K columns, same number of rows as A.

I know nonzero() can help me get index corresponding to one same label. But I don't know how to write everything **without loop**. I'm actually working on a large matrix. So using any "for" loop will definitely ruin the efficiency.

Example as following:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]

label = [1,2,3,1,2,3]

New matrix = [[1+4,2+5,3+6],
             [7+10,8+11,9+12]]

K=3, n=6
```

Comment: Please include an example of your matrix and the expected output.

Comment: I have included the example

Comment: Many things are unclear here. The `A` in the example does not have any rows or columns. It just has 12 values. There is no _"n-dim vector b"_ in the example. When you say _"Each column a_i belongs to a class."_, you mean to say that vector `b` contains a _"type index"_ for each column in `A`? I am guessing that you meant to write `A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]`, `b = [1, 2, 3]`, `result = [[1+4, 2+5, 3+6], [7+10, 8+11, 9+12]]`. Would that be it? And final question, what do you mean by `_"No loop thanks."_? Of course you need a loop, one way or another.

Comment: just edited, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
One way to avoid loops is to use map.  

    First create a func to reduce a list. 

    def red(l):
        return list(map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], zip(l[:3], l[3:])))

     A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]

Then apply map to the list of lists.  

    >>> list(map(red, A))

    [[5, 7, 9], [17, 19, 21]]

    ￼
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you are not able to use loops but here is the solution

```
import numpy as np

def masksum(v,vmask,elemn):
    vmask = list(map(lambda x: 1 if x == elemn else 0, vmask))
    a = np.array(v)
    return np.sum(a * vmask)

def mysum(v1,vmask):
    norepeat = list(set(vmask))
    return list(map(lambda elemn: masksum(v1,vmask,elemn),norepeat))

A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
label = [1,2,3,1,2,3]     
result = list(map(lambda vectori: mysum(vectori,label), A)) 
print(result)
```

label is like a mask you can try with [1,3,3,1,3,3] or [4,4,4,5,5,5] etc and the code will works